# Taxonomy term count per vocabulary

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I want to count taxonomy terms for one (or per) vocabulary. I know, it can be done via views with aggregation but I wonder if there is another way to do this without using views.

There is a taxonomy vocabulary.
There are terms in this vocabulary.
**I want to learn how many terms are there in this vocabulary.**

Is there a method to show term counts as node count below?

```
<?php $counter = db_query("SELECT count(nid) FROM {node} WHERE node.type='page' AND node.status=1")->fetchField(); ?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For count the number of term in a vocabulary you can use this method : [taxonomy_get_tree($vocabulary_id)](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_get_tree/). It will returns all the terms of the vocabulary in an array. After that, you only have to get the size of the array.

Example :

```
$terms_array = taxonomy_get_tree(9); //9 is the vocabulary ID.
$terms_nb = sizeof($terms_array); // $terms_nb = your number of terms.
```